# Nginx: redirect regardless of the url structure

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, redirect

I recently moved a subdomain to my main domain but I also changed the url structure.

Previously I had pages like `http://sub.domain.com/companies/my-company-id/year/2012/charts`

When moving to the main domain, I removed all the complicated urls to juts get:
`http://www.domain.com/companies/my-company`

I currently have the following rule:
 `rewrite ^/companies/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/companies/$1 permanent;` but when someone go on a page like `http://sub.domain.com/companies/my-company/2012/charts` they get redirect to `http://www,.domain.com/companies/my-company/2012/charts` and get a 404.

I like to force a redirection to `http://www,.domain.com/companies/my-company-id` regardless of what's after the my-company-id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the parameter $1 is having the entire URI after /companies, so you are getting redirected to the original path. You should only extract the company-id in $1.
Use this:

`rewrite ^/companies/(.*)/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/companies/$1 permanent;`

Here the rest of the URI after company-id will be available in the parameter $2, which is not needed in the rewrite condition.

Comment: I accepted this answer earlier but actually when I'm hitting http://sub.domain.com/companies/company-id nothing happens.

Comment: Place 2 rewrite rules: `rewrite ^/companies/(.*)/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/companies/$1 permanent; rewrite ^/companies/(.*)/$ http://www.domain.com/companies/$1 permanent;` for handling both the conditions. The first rewrite rule will handle URLs similar to http://sub.domain.com/companies/my-company-id/year/2012/charts and the second rule will handle redirection for sub.domain.com/companies/company-id/